# How to have a Button on click open an app on an android?

Tags: android

I have made an app that will simulate the iOS.

When the settings button is clicked i need it to open the settings on the android phone.

Same thing for all of the other icons such as the phone button will open the dialer on the android phone.

How can i do this??

EXAMPLE

iOS APP1 FOR ANDROID

Settings (image button) clicked = Android Settings opens

Phone (Image Button) clicked = Android Dialer Opens

-

Sincerely,
IntelSoftApps

-

p.s. If any one want to be part of this app/project let me know. Just send me an email at admin@intelsoftapps.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a home screen replacement app, which is what I assume you're trying to do

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

If not, you have to clarify what you're doing, because "simulating the iOS" could mean a lot of things.

Comment: yes. i am making a home replacement but it is exactly like the iphone (iOS). But my app is more customized. so i have a layout with buttons but when i want to open settings i hit the settings button and it will launch the android settings.

Comment: How is that more customised? And how is that different than any other homescreen app?

Answer (score 0):

see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) on how to do things on a click.

see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actcomp) on how to start an activity (the UI parts of an app). unluckily I don't know the intent to open settings, but I guess googling for "android settings intent" should give some results.